# error c2679 using Stream iterators with a Class

Tags: c++, class, iterator

I'm trying to create an `std::istream` iterator that uses `std::cin` to place `int`s into a class that holds two integers. However, I get:

> error c2679: Binary '>>' no operator found

when I try to define the iterator. How do I initialize the iterator?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

class data {
public:
    data() = default;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
};

std::istream_iterator<data> din(std::cin);

data daData = *din;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the intro of [`std::istream_iterator` from C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

> std::istream_iterator is a single-pass input iterator that reads successive objects of type T from the std::basic_istream object for which it was constructed, **by calling the appropriate operator>>**.

So, you need to provide the overloaded **stream extraction operator** (`>>`) for your type.

For example:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, data& d )
{
    is >> d.num1 >> d.num2;
    return is;
}
```

Here's a complete working example with overloaded *stream extraction* (`>>`) and *insertion* (`<<`) operators:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

class data
{
public:
    data() = default;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, data& d )
    {
        is >> d.num1 >> d.num2;
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const data& d )
    {
        os << "[" << d.num1 << ", " << d.num2 << "]";
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<data> din(std::cin);
    data daData = *din;

    std::cout << daData;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output with input `1 2`:

> [1, 2]

Here's the live example: https://ideone.com/1Y4TcQ

Answer (score 0):

std::istream_iterator uses operator>>(std::istream&, data&) to read data into objects. Since this operator>> requires an existing data object as parameter (to write the data into), the iterator has to construct one before it can dump the data from the stream into it, and for this it requires a default constructor.

Your data class does not have one. The easiest solution to the problem would be to give it one.

```
class data {
public:
    data() = default;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, data &);
};
```